# error in jasperserver :Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME

Tags: jasperserver

I know this may be duplicate question.

I have this error when I start my community jasperserver, and load a report has custom visualization component , and this error occur.
disappear. when I call:

```
http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/reportresource/reportresource?resource=com/jaspersoft/jasperreports/customvisualization/resources/require/cv-component.js
```

nothing returns, so this may be the problem right ?

but when I start the jasperserver commercial version , this error disappear. when I call:

```
http://localhost:8080/jasperserver-pro/reportresource/reportresource?resource=com/jaspersoft/jasperreports/customvisualization/resources/require/cv-component.js
```

it returns the content of this `cv-component.js`.

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

the trick (which wored for me after hours of triel-and-error) is to set the proper configuration in jasperreports.properties (on an windows machine):

com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.components.customvisualization.require.js=file:/C:/path/to/require.js

net.sf.jasperreports.web.resource.pattern.customvisualization.scripts=com/jaspersoft/jasperreports/customvisualization/resources/require/.*

See the "file:/...." and "...require/.* specially... (a bit different than in teh jaspersoft docs...)

Cheers, Thomas